# elasticsearch Command line tools not found

Tags: elasticsearch

I have installed elasticsearch on Linux 18 and
I trying to run the following command:

```
elasticsearch-node detach-cluster
```

But I get the following error: `command not found`

I see these commands from Elasticearch Documentation ([here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/commands.html)).
How do I execute this command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending of your installation, you should find the bin/ of elasticsearch,
I most cases is in /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin

example:

```
# /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-node 
A CLI tool to do unsafe cluster and index manipulations on current node

Non-option arguments:
command              

Option             Description        
------             -----------        
-E <KeyValuePair>  Configure a setting
-h, --help         Show help          
-s, --silent       Show minimal output
-v, --verbose      Show verbose output
ERROR: Missing command
```